# Asp.net core api getting "415 Unsupported Media Type" error from Javascript, not Postman

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I've created an Asp.Net Core Web Application and am looking to implement a Web API.

I've got a functional HttpGet implemented and am now trying to implement a HttpPost function:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public object Post([FromBody] object data)
    {            
        return null;
    }
```

I've tested this using Postman which worked fine. 
I set it up with json object in the body (set to raw and JSON (application/json)).

I get the expected response.

But when I try to call this from javascript using code suggested by Postman (or my own attempts):

```js
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://localhost:51139/api/data",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "999ee8ee-4e92-acb8-b7cf-144ffa49e5ee"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": "{\"Message\":\"This is body data\"}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

I get a "415 Unsupported Media Type" error.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: From where you call the javascript ? From a page ? From another Site ?

Comment: I just have it in a simple html page which I open in a browser. There's no webserver or anything like that.

Comment: If I run the code from a page on a simple webserver, I get the same response.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried a million different combinations (`$.ajax`, `$.post` etc), but what finally did it was the `accepts: "application/json"`:

```js
{
    type: "post",
    accepts: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:51139/api/data",
    contentType : "application/json",
    data: "{\"Message\":\"This is body data\"}"
}
```

Comment: It was this post that reminded me to use contentType: "application/json".  That did it for me.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: @user1883961 Great! Glad it was helpful in some way! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public object Post()
{   
    Object o = Request.Form.First(o => o.Key == "data").Value 
    return null;
}
```

Then if you can create a class of that object you can use JsonConvert to Deserialize that object into the class object that you have created.

Comment: I get a 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'Incorrect Content-Type: application/json'' error when I tried this (with small corrections to the code).

Comment: Try decorating your controller with [Produces("application/json")]. Then ensure you have made a C# model instead of using generic object. 
This is probably failing due to .net being unable to bind your model with what is receiving. 
So to recap keep your code the same but Create a c# model of your data and decorate it with the [Produces("application/json")].
Hope this helps